# Discrimination against intelligence

Tags: single-word-requests

In the same vein as "racism", "sexism", "anti-semitism" etc., is there a word that describes being discriminatory against people of great intelligence?

Comment: Are you asking about being against people who *are* intelligent (who have a high IQ) or about people who *exhibit* signs of intellect—such as scholars or philosophers?

Comment: There is a degree of *[anti-intellectualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-intellectualism)* present in some segments of our society.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica both/either

Comment: Trumpism perhaps?

Comment: You may need to invent a word for your purposes. I suggest sapiophobia. If a sapiosexual person is turned on by the intelligence of another person, perhaps a sapiophile would really love geniuses, while a sapiophobe would be deathly afraid of them. Just a suggestion. Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Anti-intellectualism** https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-intellectual

> opposing or hostile to intellectuals or to an intellectual view or approach

Wikipedia currently describes it as

> Anti-intellectualism is hostility to and mistrust of intellect, intellectuals, and intellectualism commonly expressed as deprecation of education and philosophy, and the dismissal of art, literature, and science as impractical and even contemptible human pursuits.